# prove：If $A=B\cup C$，and $|A|=| \mathbb{R} |$ ，then then either  or  must have the same cardinality as ℝ .

Tags: analysis

I totally have no idea how to make up the mapping between B and R. 
If f is the mapping between A and R, how to continue this proof?
Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: You will receive more help if you show what you attempted

Comment: I think you mean "then either $B$ or $C$ must have the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$." Please edit your title if this is the case $-$ people are having trouble understanding what you mean by "between $B$ and $C$."

Comment: Yes that's what I want to express

Comment: How much of set and cardinality theory may you use/do you know?

Comment: Only a little. I just started learning real-analysis several days ago

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of [cardinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_arithmetic), in particular cardinal addition and is based on axiom of choice.

For two cardinals $\kappa, \mu$, you have
$$\kappa + \mu = \max\{\kappa,\mu\}$$

Comment: Goog answer.  This may be all yLccc needs.  (Or maybe not, yLccc provides no information to let us find out.)  Another question may be: in the special case of $|\mathbb R|$, is there a proof not using the axiom of choice?

Comment: @GEdgar. Good question... which I have to admit is beyond my skills!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean between set B and C. If you mean the union of B,C then by definition of A the question is trivial.

However if it means other thing it doesn't even seems to pass the test of B={1,2},C={2,3}

Comment: Your A doesn't have the cardinal of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: See my comment to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

So, the statement can be trivialized by some set and cardinality theory, but it seems funnier to provide a proof where only the simplest version of AC is used.

Consider a bijection $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $D=f(C)$. Assume that $D$ does have a lower cardinality than $|\mathbb{R}|$. In particular, no co-finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be injected into $D$.

There is an injection $D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ yielding an injection $D \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which we denote as $g$.

Let $D’=\{x \in \mathbb{R},\,g(D,x) \cap D \neq \emptyset\}$. Clearly, there is an injection $D’ \rightarrow D$ because $g$ is injective. As a consequence (first paragraph), we obtain that $\mathbb{R} \backslash D’$ is infinite, and thus there is an infinite set $I$ and an injection ($g_{|D \times I}$) from $D \times I$ to $\mathbb{R} \backslash D=f(B)$.

In particular, $D \times \mathbb{N}$ can be injected into $B$, which shows that there is an injection $C \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow B$, whicch shows that there is an injection $B \cup C \rightarrow B$, and thus $\mathbb{R}$ can be injected into $B$ and the conclusion follows from Cantor-Bernstein.